# Eiffel: Creating a datetime with '' format

Tags: eiffel

Seems I'm wrong creating a datetime from string using this method, any idea why? The precondition violates on `date_time_valid: date_time_valid (s, code)`

```
create l_date_time.make_from_string ("2019-03-28T15:28:02Z", "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ssZ")
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://www.eiffel.org/doc/solutions/DATE_TIME_to_STRING_Conversion), the characters `'T'` and `'Z'` are not valid format specifiers. Therefore, they need to be replaced with valid ones and the format string should be changed accordingly:

```
        s := "2019-03-28T15:28:02Z"
        s.replace_substring_all ("T", " ")
        s.replace_substring_all ("Z", "")
        create t.make_from_string (s, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss")
```

Comment: do you know a reason why not to support iso standards? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: @Pipo The library was developed in 1996 when ISO 8601 was not that widely adopted. Since then, although the library is open source, nobody submitted a patch to support ISO 8601, so it does not look like a priority for users, or they are happy with home-grown solutions.